# C++11 variadic template parameter expansion

Tags: c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I would like to do the following:

```
template<typename Func>
class FunctionWrapper
{
public:
    typedef decltype(Func()) ReturnType;
    typedef ... ArgsType;

    FunctionWrapper(Func func)
    {
        func_ = func;
    }

    ReturnType operator() (ArgsType args)
    {
        return func_(args);
    }
private:
    Func func_;
};
```

The problem is I don't know how to deduce the ArgsType from Func type. I'd like to make it work when the function returns/accepts nothing as well.

The usecase would then be:

```
FunctionWrapper<myFunction> wrapper;
auto result = wrapper(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: You can make `operator()` a template member function and forward its arguments to `func_`.

Comment: @Lingxi is there a way to make it work with having the ArgsType deduced at the time of declaring the wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the argument and return type(s) in `operator()` and use perfect forwarding:

```
template <typename Func>
class FunctionWrapper
{
    Func func_;

public:

    FunctionWrapper(Func func) : func_(func) {}

    template <typename... Args>
    auto operator() (Args&&... args)
      -> decltype(func_(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) {
        return    func_(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Comment: With g++-4.8 -std=c++11 and the following example: `double myFunc(double a) {
    return a;
}

FunctionWrapper(myFunc) wrap;` this gives me `error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’`

Comment: @iggy Whoops, that was a typo. Fixed.

Comment: thanks! But is there a way to say something like this: 
`auto res = FunctionWrapper(myFunc)(0.0);` without getting `error: missing template arguments before ‘(’ token`?

Comment: You can make a helper function like `std::make_pair`.

Comment: @iggy Use a factory function. I.e. `template <typename F> FunctionWrapper<F>  makeWrapper (F f)  {return {f};}`

Comment: @Columbo awesome... Why does type deduction not work when you use it directly with the class but works when you have a factory function?

Comment: figured it out.. the full class declaration must be available before we can use it

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way to do that, neither is it logical. Just think of the case when `Func` overloads `operator()` and accepts different argument types. You could, however, mandates that `Func` defines its argument type as a member type for utility like `FunctionWrapper` to access. See the possible member types of [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) for an example.